# Order By doesn't work with Left Join -MySQL / Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sql-order-by

I have my query above, it retrieves the data fine but the ordering is off. I am trying to order the results by Price. Not sure if I need to add another GROUP BY param or I need to add another join. Anyone else had the same issue?

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID,wp_postmeta1.meta_value AS sku, wp_postmeta2.meta_value AS Price
                        FROM wp_posts
                        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta1
                            ON wp_postmeta1.post_id = wp_posts.ID
                            AND wp_postmeta1.meta_key = '_sku'
                        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta2
                            ON wp_postmeta2.post_id = wp_posts.ID
                            AND wp_postmeta2.meta_key = '_price'
                        WHERE (wp_posts.post_type = 'product'
                        AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
                        AND wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%abi%')
                        OR (wp_posts.post_type = 'product'
                        AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
                        AND wp_postmeta1.meta_value LIKE '%abi%'  )
                        GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
                        ORDER BY wp_postmeta2.meta_value ASC
                        LIMIT 15
```

Comment: The columns returned other than wp_posts.ID will be indeterminate (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and there are no aggregate functions so gorup by isn't appropriate here

Comment: You are using wp_query or custom query

Comment: I am using a custom query, also if I don't use group by I will get the same ID returned multiple times. I believe if I used wp_query I would need to use 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',

Answer (score 0):

Using cast fixed the sorting.
ORDER BY CAST(wp_postmeta2.meta_value as unsigned) ASC